# sharing session between two wars in a single ear

Tags: session, share, glassfish-3

I have an ear that packages two wars. war 1 has all the forms for authentication and war 2 has the applications that the user can use. The user is redirected from the home page in war 1 to the application home page in war 2 by a hyperlink. When the user logs in, and navigates to a page in war 2, the session is lost as the context is different and a new context creates a new session(as per my understanding). Is there any way that i can share the session data between the two contexts ? I am using JSF 2.1 and glassfish 3 server with netbeans

Comment: Is the problem the session itself or the user login?

Comment: Once i login in the first context and navigate to the second one, the session is lost and the user has to login again. None of the session attributes i set in the first one reaches the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled this using WAS session sharing ability that allows me to share session between the 2 WARs in the same ear.
But after that I faced another problem with shared session with JSF that the navigation rules of the 2 wars some how mixed up,as an example when I move from 1st war to the 2nd war using hyperlink when I navigate through the 2nd war I got this error from JSF:

> No navigation case match for viewId /dir1/dir2/war2page1.xhtml, action #{springManagedBean.beanAction(param)} and outcome navigationOutcomeName

as it seems that sharing session some how makes the navigation rules of the 1st WAR is replacing the navigation rules of the 2nd WAR.

Answer (score -1):

You can save it in the ServletContext, instead of the session. The servletcontext keep values until the server is down. There are some topics, here, who explain how to share a data through different servletcontexts